# Percent of practical questions

Tags: discussion

I don't know is it crucial question, but I think it is important to mention discuss at least.

Being on the site for 5 months I keep seeing that biggest part (like 95%) of questions are belong to 2 categories:

1. Here is a good puzzle I know. I solved it myself and want to share my pleasure with others. Try to solve it.
   Random examples:

   1. [9 Diggin men](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2773/men-digging-holes/2777#2777)
   2. [The Hardest Logic Puzzle Ever](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2665/another-knights-and-knaves)
   3. [Round Robin Tournament](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75/round-robin-tournament)
2. I heard about this thing and just wonder, what would be result if ... 
   Random examples:

   1. [Largest tile in 2048](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48/what-is-the-largest-tile-possible-in-2048)
   2. [How many intervals can be measured with N burning robes?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/170/burning-ropes-as-timers-how-many-time-intervals-can-be-measured)
   3. [How many distinct unsolvable Rubik's cubes exist?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/525/how-many-distinct-unsolvable-rubiks-cubes-exist)

All of them I would call "not practical". That means **OP doesn't really want an answer to** his/her question. This is not bad, since it still let people to store the knowledge on the site, but this is very untypical for StackExchange and leads to encouragement
 of things, which are usually not welcome on StackExchange, for example, skipping critical knowledge, which will help a lot to people, who want to answer the question; or skipping personal investigation of the problem.

Thats basically it. I just would like to know what other people thing about this situation. Hope such a question is ok for Meta.

Comment: Don't forget the type "I thought of this puzzle, can you solve?"

Comment: You made quiet a few typos... "is it crucial question", "mouths", "thats", "I just would like to know" I think you meant if it is a crucial question,  months, that's, I would just like to know

Comment: I'm personally not against "solve this puzzle I made" because it's original and interesting. It beats the hell out of re-hashing Knights and Knaves sixteen times

Comment: @warspyking, I think "I thought of this puzzle, how many solutions does it have?" (or "can you prove that it has the only solution", or something like this) is definitely what should be on the site, since this is question about puzzle creation. And OP doesn't know the answer and really wants it.